# How to get non-distinct results from a hibernate query using "in"

Tags: java, hibernate

```
List<Prize> prizes =
                sessionProvider.getCurrentSession().createQuery("from Prize where id in (:ids)")
                        .setParameterList("ids", prizeIds).list();
```

I have a list of prizeIds, which are not unique. I need to fetch Prize objects for each id. But hibernate returns me only unique elements list. How can i get a list same size as the input list.

Comment: id's are not unique ??? scaring me dude !!.Little fishy currently,Please clarify.

Comment: ids in the table are unique. But the list I pass (prizeIds) will conatin the same id multiple times.

Comment: You can iterate over ids list and get result from current session and add these object to your return list.

Comment: I was looking for a direct query .. but i think thats the only way to go

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE**: The thing that you collection has multiple ids changes the things. Certainly Hibernate is doing his job so you must find another solution.

To answear the question properly: It is impossible to get non-distinct results using "in".

Comment: no, my id list is not distinct. eg; prizeIds = {1,3,2,1,1,4}, fot this i need s list of Prize objects containing {P1, P3, P2, P1, P1, P4}. But what hibernate returns me is {P1,P2,P3,P4}

Answer (score 1):

The answer you are getting is default functionality of "in" function in database. Use exist or not exist clause to retrieve the records for every id. I doubt whether you can use exist or not exists as well.

But, be sure about the functionality you are trying to achieve, this is not something very common in most of the applications